# Cant upgrade from ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, 23.04, 23.10

In the update app if i open no version is said to be upgrade to the new version.
I have ubuntu 23.04.
I have all updates installed.
And in the definitions is set to upgrade to any version of ubuntu

What can i do to upgrade to ubuntu 23.10 from ubuntu 23.04?
and is a way to do it from the update app?

so far in my laptop its still not avaiable upgrade from ubuntu 23.04 to ubuntu 23.10 in the update app. is this still something to happen as the comment bellow says or is something wrong with my system?

Comment: I have upgraded the os by the command: sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: decided to do a fresh install of ubuntu 23.10 after some weeks of waiting to have enable the upgrade

Answer (score 39):

The release of Ubuntu 23.10 has not actually completed.

You can refer to this notice for clues

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcement-ubuntu-desktop-23-10-release-image-is-being-updated-to-resolve-a-malicious-translation-incident/39365

The respins of ISOs were done, and are currently in QA (*Quality Assurance*) testing, the status you can view by looking at

https://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/449/builds

Currently the respun ISOs are not marked "(ready)" you'll note.

After the ISOs are released, and the release cycle of Ubuntu 23.10 completes; the Ubuntu Release team will explore the option of opening the *upgrade* cycle

The [Ubuntu release upgrader tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-upgrader) check this file for status of upgrade

- https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release

which is simple text (*thus easily read*) where you'll note no Ubuntu 23.10 currently lists; that is why the upgrade process is not seen.

You can force *release-upgrade* via use of `-d` as per instructions provided on Ubuntu 23.10 release notes & announcements, ie. read this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades

The `-d` works as it will force use of the following file, where *mantic* or 23.10 is seen

- https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development

For best results; I suggest waiting though. I've seen 9+ emails hitting my inbox on the weekend representing work being performed on the *release-upgrade* bugs, the upgrade path will be open when the current work is completed.

Ubuntu 23.10 currently hasn't fully released; but the release is the initial step for new installs. After release completes, the *Ubuntu Release team* start evaluating the *release-upgrade* steps, opening the *taps* when its deemed ready; which has not occurred yet.

Comment: I'll add some detail here on perspective.  I'm a *Lubuntu team member*, we got the *go ahead* from the Ubuntu Release team telling us we could release; thus with my Lubuntu *hat* on, Lubuntu 23.10 is fully released (*we use the `calamares` installer which isn't impacted, thus received no 'hold' order*). I'm also a *Ubuntu News* member too, and no Ubuntu 23.10 release notice has yet been published to [Ubuntu Fridge](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/), as the *Ubuntu Release* team hasn't got to their ML announcement yet for the 23.10 release; Ubuntu 23.10 release is still in progress.

Comment: I just noted the ISOs for 23.10.1 (*note version details on the iso.qa tracker*) have changed..  It's an "*essentially no-op rebuild*" but again more testing is required... thus delay

Comment: New 23.10 ISOs are fully up & ready for download, in fact Ubuntu 23.10 has completed it's release cycle :)

Comment: do ypu kow when the upgrade will be avaiable on the update app?

Comment: No I don't know, my estimation will be early next week but that's just opinion. Anyone can look at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-23-10-release-status-tracking/37887 to see, with the *blocker* bug listed getting a fix late on 18-October-2023 (*it was into 19th-October my local time actually*) my suspicion is the *Ubuntu Release* team would wait until early in the week (*as is their custom*) rather than before a weekend.

Comment: Update on prior 'estimation' of open; the update bug *fix* can only be fully implemented (*I was just told*) when *nn* opens (allowing *mantic* itself to be fixed). When that occurs I don't know; from *artful* thru *lunar* were much faster than *mantic* was; *nn* opening is on par currently with *mantic* (as regards opening).

Comment: @TiagoEarth Please consider marking this answer as Accepted, as the author went out of their way to give a very thorough/complete one here.

Comment: Two weeks later and the changelogs file still doesn't have 23.10 in it. Any idea why this is taking so long...?

Comment: Two weeks? @k-war; my last update was 19 October which was ~one week ago. Progress occurs; "*nn*" I mention has opened with my system reporting "*OS: Lubuntu Noble N (development branch) x86_64*" (even if animal not known). It may open early next week, but its up to *Ubuntu Release team* who traditionally open *taps* early in week, and monitor bugs reported by those who *force* upgrade more closely than I do. Work progresses & everyone can monitor via https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-23-10-release-status-tracking/37887

Comment: @guiverc thanks!

Comment: @k-war just FYI.. but maybe 10 mins after I wrote that last comment; the *N* animal-name was publicly available (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2023-October/001341.html) which is a *local* animal for me too :)

Comment: For users reading this; also reading https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491247/i-upgraded-to-ubuntu-23-10-early-i-notice-the-upgrade-was-delayed-is-something maybe beneficial  (*give it time, this upgrade may not need to be manually resolved as per this link*)

Comment: This question/answer is now *outdated* and should be required anymore.. the key *metafile* https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release now shows Ubuntu 23.10 as *supported* and thus upgrades should now be found (*without requiring the `-d` option*)

Answer (score 6):

Just wait a couple of days.

Some Ubuntu 23.10 images have been delayed due to offensive [translations](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcement-ubuntu-desktop-23-10-release-image-is-being-updated-to-resolve-a-malicious-translation-incident/39365).

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 23.10 has been released already, but usually Ubuntu doesn't let you upgrade inmediately. If you want to get the version now, you could download it [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: The release notes (*and announcements too if you follow links*)  told users how to upgrade via https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades   The *upgrade* needs to be forced with `-d` as documented on release notes (inc. my answer) unless users wait for the *Ubuntu Release team* to open the path once it's deemed *stable*.