# Why is Ubuntu 23.10 still not showing up in meta-releases?

Tags: 23.10

To my knowledge do-release-upgrade looks in this file https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release for an upgrade path. We're two weeks past the 23.10 release and it is still not showing up there.

I know you can use the "-d" parameter but to my understanding that points to a development release which I rather not use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant upgrade from ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489169/cant-upgrade-from-ubuntu-23-04-to-23-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have just found the answer, https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-23-10-release-status-tracking/37887 says:

> Current blockers for enabling upgrades Text becomes unreadable on
> Ubuntu MATE during upgrade due to replacement of system font on disk
> 182

Which I suppose explains why it's not showing up as a release.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with k-war. The [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/2034986) has been seems to have been fixed on 27 October, then some testings are needed hence why it took some time.

Finally the meta-release file has been updated to include Mantic as on 2 November, alongside the [announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2023-October/001341.html) that work is starting for Noble Numbat.