# I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 early; i notice the upgrade was delayed; is something missing?

Tags: do-release-upgrade, 23.10

I noted on the [Ubuntu 23.10 release announcements](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/10/16/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-released/), a link to upgrading *early* was provided via https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades

I also notice on the [Ubuntu *Mantic Minotaur* (23.10) Release Status Tracking](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-23-10-release-status-tracking/37887) that it's still *in progress*.

I forced upgrade using the *ManticUpgrades* link (using `-d`), is anything missing in my early upgraded system?

Comment: Yeah this post is engineered (*another for notification purposes*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status tracking document listed noted a current blocker.

As was just upgraded in this [Mailing List post by Brian Murray](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2023-November/042836.html) (Ubuntu Release Team)

> Due to a bug in snapd [1], which is now resolved, users who upgraded
> early to mantic will not have received the firmware-updater snap [2].
> You can install the snap via:
>
> `snap install --channel latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10 firmware-updater`
>
> [1] http://launchpad.net/bugs/2039268
>
> [2] https://snapcraft.io/firmware-updater

Execute this command and your system should be fully-upgraded.

```
guiverc@d7050-next:~/blah/python3-defaults-3.11.4$   snap install --channel latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10 firmware-updater
firmware-updater 0+git.e8771be from Canonical✓ installed
```

Comment: FYI:  My system was already upgraded to *noble*, but as per that ML post it was not running the latest (*despite my upgrading three times already today*). I'd expect the same (*currently anyway*) for users using Ubuntu 23.10 or *mantic*.